ZebraDesigner for Developers | How to use Text variables with any font?
I'm using "ZebraDesigner for Developers" to generate ZPL code for label and send it to a printer.
My issue is that I need to have Text as variable (and this variable will be set when sending the ZPL code using python) but ZebraDesigner raise an error if this text is not using Printer font. In order to match the sticker spec, I need to have the text in Arial font. Is there a way to use any font with variable text ?
Other point, is that "Zebra Swiss Unicode" font (which can be used with text variable) doesn't print the way it looks in the user interface. Is there some settings to be change to have the correct preview ? Or why the sticker doesn't match the preview ?
I try different font and settings but couldn't find a way to fix my issues?
